# Self Join Condition with Specific Amount

Tags: sql, oracle

Goal: **Display employees and their salary with very least like 2100 only.**

How do I put conditions in my query where the salary should be = 2100?

Query:

```sql
SELECT e.first_name ||' with the salary of '|| d.salary 
AS Employees_and_their_Salary
FROM hr.employees e 
JOIN hr.employees d
ON e.manager_id = d.employee_id;
```

The expected output shou:

[image: Desired Output]

The Database that I use is the [Oracle HR Objects and Data for LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_GV8MU6SITA2V3VYI179FAJUCY.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a where condition -

```
SELECT e.first_name ||' with the salary of '|| d.salary 
AS Employees_and_their_Salary
FROM hr.employees e 
JOIN hr.employees d ON e.manager_id = d.employee_id
WHERE d.salary = 2100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ummm ... why are you self-joining that table? Output you want doesn't suggest you need it. What's wrong with simple

```
SELECT e.first_name ||' with the salary of '|| e.salary AS Employees_and_their_Salary
FROM hr.employees e 
WHERE e.salary = 2100;
```

Comment: The instruction that was given to me is that I should use self-join or cross-join. Since it only uses 1 table, I chose the self-join.

Comment: How was that "instruction" justified? It just doesn't make any sense. Everything you need is in a single table and no join is needed. You *would* need it if you had to display e.g. employee, their salary and manager's name - then yes, you'd self-join the table. But - with data you need right now, no joins.